# PHP Check connect to Remote SSL Address

Tags: php, ssl, connection

Is there any reliable way via PHP to check if a local WebServer (php4) can access a remote SSL address ?

https://xxx.yyy.com
port 443 ?

All I'm interested in ensuring is the connection from the WebServer to the remote address is working and on port 443. I'm not bothered about checking certificates etc..

Thanks

UPDATE:

I've tried this, but is it reliable ?

```
<?php 
function checkConnection() 
{ 
    $conn = @fsockopen("www.abc.com", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 
    if ($conn)
    { 
        $status = "Connection is OK";  
        fclose($conn);
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "NO Connection<br/>\n";
        $status .= "$errstr ($errno)"; 
    }
    return $status; 
}

echo checkConnection();
?>
```

Comment: Have you found this method to be unreliable? There are many factors that could affect the connection reliability to remote servers.

Comment: I've tried it several times and it does seem to work. but I want to make sure it's 100% reliable.

Comment: As long as the network is stable and you have no connectivity issues this, the code, should be reliable.

Comment: Thanks I'll stick with that then :D